# Will most Michigan families get a tax hike due to the new tax bill?

Tags: united-states, taxes, michigan

Debbie Stabenow, US Senator for Michigan, [claimed](https://www.facebook.com/stabenow/posts/10155666285710528)

> Thanks to President Trump and the Republicans, most Michigan families will get a tax hike.

Looking at the proposed tax brackets I don't understand how "most" Michigan families would experience a tax increase.

Is this a true claim?  Will the majority of Michigan families have an increase in taxes?

Edit: what this post means by *most* is whether more than 50% of people in Michigan would have their taxes increase.

Comment: What do you mean by most: mean or median change, some other value?

Comment: @DrunkCynic: Does the last sentence not make it clear?  "Will the majority of Michigan families have an increase in taxes?"

Comment: How long a period are you considering? Due to the mechanism used to pass it, a lot of the individual tax cuts in the bill have to expire within 10 years,

Comment: @origimbo Most tax cuts have sunsets, and a decade is two presidential elections and 4 congressional elections away.  I'd be surprised if there was a valid reason to consider a longer period of time than the tax cut itself, but if you feel strongly that this is a valid way to explain her statement then please add an answer using whatever methodology fits the statement and clearly explain what it is and why you believe it's a valid model.

Comment: This is hard to tell *on a state level* because main data (e.g. how many are using standard deductions vs. itemize, how many have child tax credit and mortgages) as far as I know are only available in aggregate from IRS, not broken out by state. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Ekadh  What is the point of that edit?  This is an old and unfortunately now irrelevant question.  Your edit doesn't clarify the question and contains a spelling mistake. I see no benefit in edits to old questions that don't substantially improve them.

Comment: @JamesK somebody got confused in the comment, and I wanted to make sure that more people wouldn’t get confused in the future. Also, my bad on the spelling mistake. As for not doing small edits to old posts, I believe that since SE is a data repository, improving old posts (even by a small amount) is a good idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is now obsolete and so will never be answered